# Xamarin.Forms get Resource from other xaml file in C# class

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, xamarin.forms

i'm trying to get resource from ResourceDictionary that's called Secretskeys.xaml in DbConnection.cs class. But no matter what i do i still get KeyNotFoundException when i try to use

```
_DbLogib = (string)Application.Current.Resources["DbLogin"];
```

But i have no problem to get API key from this file in other xaml files. I'm trying to make static class that will work with database, and in secretkeys.xaml i have all password's and api keys.

Here is how Directory looks like:
[Directory in Rider](https://i.stack.imgur.com/myt8q.png)

Answer (score 0):

Here is a workaround.

First, you should merge resource dictionaries,

In App.xaml,

```
<Application.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
         <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
            <ResourceDictionary Source="Secretskeys.xaml" />
         </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>

...
```

Then you could retrieve the value using

```
Application.Current.Resources.TryGetValue("DBLogin", out var myvalue)

Console.WriteLine((string)myvalue); // You could check the value
```

Please let me know if you have any question.